# lateinit property binding has not been initialized when using from other class

Tags: android, kotlin

In the `MainActivity` class I use this snippet:

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
```

And I'm trying to access textView from other class like this

`MainActivity().binding.textView.text`

but I'm getting `lateinit property binding has not been initialized` error on this line? Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you you're calling MainActivity(), you're effectively creating a new instance of MainActivity, but it hasn't been bound to any lifecycle (thus not calling onCreate(), thus not inflating your layout).

If you're trying to access the activity from a fragment, call:

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).binding.textView.text
```

Edit: do note that this approach will throw an error if your fragment is hosted by a different activity than MainActivity

Comment: What I did is placing `lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding` outside the class but thanks for alternative solution.

Comment: @LabaDiena Don't do that. You are leaking your views outside your activity, keeping them in memory after the Activity is already destroyed.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks. Sometimes I get answers but don't get suggestions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So, MikkeIT's answer is also bad practice?

Comment: No, it’s fine as long as you aren’t copying the binding or view reference into another property.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var callAPI: CallAPIAsyncTask = CallAPIAsyncTask()
```

lite this